# Does anyone have a way to disable this warning: Warning: [antd: Checkbox] `value` is not a valid prop, do you mean `checked`?

Tags: antd, react-testing-library

I'm rendering a checkbox compoment from antd v4+ and I have a warnings `Warning: [antd: Checkbox]`value`is not a valid prop, do you mean`checked`?`

Heres is my code:

```
import { Checkbox, Form, Typography } from '@90poe/antdv4';
import React, { FC } from 'react';

import type { Option } from '../types';

interface Props {
    item: Option;
    onClick?: (e: Option) => void;
}

export const Test: FC<Props> = ({ item }: Props) => {
    const { value } = item;

    return (
        <Form.Item valuePropName="checked" noStyle>
            <Checkbox value={value} key={value}>
                <Typography.Text>Test</Typography.Text>
            </Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
    );
};
```

Here is also what I tried

```
<Form.Item name="checkbox">
  {getFieldDecorator('order_receiver', {
      defaultChecked: true,
      rules: [
          {
              required: false,
              message:
                  'Offer!',
          },
      ],
      valuePropName:"checked"
  })(
       <Checkbox value={value} key={value}>
                <Typography.Text>Test</Typography.Text>
            </Checkbox>
  )}
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `value` is not a valid props of component `Checkbox`

The error suggests you to try props `checked` instead like this.

```
<Checkbox checked={value} key={value}>
  <Typography.Text>Test</Typography.Text>
</Checkbox>
```

Be sure to pass a boolean in this props.